# How to implement storage for ngxs managed state in an electron app

Tags: electron, ngxs

I am using Angular and ngxs as state management solution in an Electron application. Now I would like to save the state in the users home directory (as simple json file).

Does anybody know how to do this. Do I have to write my own ngxs plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use @ngxs/storage-plugin and write an own implementation of the interface StorageEngine. (see https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/storage#options)

But in this case an async behaviour is required. Because of you have to read a file with nodejs file API (e.g. readFileSync which returns a promise)

For that purpose, there is also a plugin available (https://github.com/ngxs-labs/async-storage-plugin). At this time it is only in alpha stage but seems to work...